# Struggling with CSS &::before, &::after

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a fancy calculator Using Html, JS and CSS. However I am really struggling with this  &::before, &::after. I have no idea why it is not working, I tried rewriting everything, using different punctuation and double-checking everything but I am not sure what is wrong. It is my first time working with it so I am quiet lost in this area yet.
`code`

```
&::before,
&::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

&::after {
  clear: both;
}
```

`code`

Another example in which it shows mistakes and highlights all the ":":
`code`

```
&:hover {
  background: #201e40;
}

&:focus {
  outline: 0; 

  /* The value fade-ins that appear */
  &::after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    animation: zoom 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
    content: attr(data-num);
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 100px;
    position: absolute;
         top: 1.5em;
         left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -24px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 48px;    
  }
}
```

Thank You in Advance <3

Comment: There is no `&` in CSS. Are you talking about Sass, aka SCSS?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use `SCSS/SASS` in your project or just a plain `CSS` ?

From the details of your question I assume that you use `CSS`.
Then you should be aware that you can not use `&` functionality and nested elements inside `CSS`. (but it can be used if you use `SCSS` instead)

For example instead of using `&`:

```
&:after
```

you need to use a selector name

```
.selectorName:after
```

And then instead of nested selectors:

```
.selector1 {
  .selector2 {
  }
}
```

you should use separate selectors

```
.selector1 { }
.selector1 .selector2 { }
```

An example how your code looks in `CSS` format:

```css
.calculatorButton { }

.calculatorButton:hover {
  background: #201e40;
}

.calculatorButton:focus {
  outline: 0; 
}

/* The value fade-ins that appear */
.calculatorButton:focus::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  animation: zoom 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: both; 
  content: attr(data-num);
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
       top: 1.5em;
       left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -24px;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  width: 48px;    
}
```

```html
<button data-num="10" class="calculatorButton">10</button>
```

Comment: Thank You so much! I haven't used the SCSS/SASS before and just trying to learn more about CSS and I did not know about not using &. Helped to fix my mistakes for sure XD Thank you again!